Assembly Nasm error - zsh: segmentation fault
section .data

    NULL equ 0 
    EXIT_SUCCESS equ 0 
    SYS_exit equ 60 

    hit db "Hit! etiqueta is already filled", 0xA  
    hit_len equ $ - hit 
    
    miss db "Miss! etiqueta will be filled", 0xA  
    miss_len equ $ - miss   
    
    etiqueta_igual db "same etiqueta", 0xA  
    etiqueta_igual_len equ $ - etiqueta_igual 
    
    indice db 0b0000
    
    masc_etiqueta dw 0b111111111000000
    etiqueta dw 0, NULL
   

section .text

extern set_validation_bit
extern set_tag
extern get_data
extern display_table
extern get_validation_bit
extern get_tag


global _start
_start:


    mov r12, rdi 
    cmp r12, 1
    jl _Done
        
    mov r13, rsi 
    mov rbx, 1


_vector_Arg_Loop_For:

;1.
    movzx rsi, word [r13 + rbx * 8]  
    mov cx, word [rsi]
    xchg cl, ch
    
    mov dx, cx
    and dx, [masc_etiqueta] 
    shr dx, 6
    mov [etiqueta], dx

;2.
    cmp dx, 0b0000000110000101   ; shr (aA and [masc_etiqueta]), 6 = 0b0000000110000101
    jne _comp_etiquetas_e_set_tag
    
    xor rax, rax
    mov rax, 1           
    mov rdi, 1           
    mov rsi, etiqueta_igual     
    mov rdx, etiqueta_igual_len 
    syscall
    
    
_comp_etiquetas_e_set_tag:

;3.
    movzx edi, byte[indice]  
    call get_tag
    cmp rax, [etiqueta]
    je _print_Hit
  
    movzx edi, byte [indice]
    movzx esi, word [etiqueta]      
    call set_tag  
    jmp _print_Miss


_print_Hit:

    xor rax, rax
    mov rax, 1           
    mov rdi, 1           
    mov rsi, hit     
    mov rdx, hit_len 
    syscall
    
    jmp _vector_Arg_Loop_Ciclo
    
    
_print_Miss: 

    xor rax, rax
    mov rax, 1           
    mov rdi, 1           
    mov rsi, miss     
    mov rdx, miss_len 
    syscall
    
    
_vector_Arg_Loop_Ciclo:

;4.                  
   inc rbx
   cmp rbx, r12
   jl _vector_Arg_Loop_For                                 
                                          
                                                
_Done:

   mov rax, SYS_exit
   mov rdi, EXIT_SUCCESS
   syscall
                      


The code's objective is to receive a certain number of arguments and process them one by one, swapping the letters, Aa -> aA, and using a mask to isolate the first 10 bits and then rotate them 6 bits to the right, making the most significant bit stay in the first 10 bits.
After processing the argument, compare it with a word and if it is equal, print a warning string -> same etiqueta
Then call the external function call get_tag which will return the last etiqueta via the rax register, if it exists, if the last etiqueta is equal to the current one, print -> Hit! tag is already filled, if not the etiqueta is updated by the current one with the external function set_tag and print -> Miss! tag will be filled
After all this, start all over again with the next argument

what I received:
┌──(mattandmello㉿MattandMello)-[~/Desktop]
└─$ ./program Aa Bb Bb
zsh: segmentation fault  ./program Aa Bb Bb
what was i waiting for:
┌──(mattandmello㉿MattandMello)-[~/Desktop]
└─$ ./validationBitSiml Aa Bb Bb
same etiqueta
Miss! etiqueta will be filled
Miss! etiqueta will be filled
Hit! etiqueta is already filled
biblioteca.o is were I have the external functions
$ nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf program.asm
$ gcc program.o biblioteca.o -o program -nostartfiles -fPIE -no-pie -lncurse

When you run gdb ./program, and inside GDB run Aa Bb Bb, which instruction segfaults?  What register values?  (And any other relevant debugging info.)  I was actually going to try it myself out of curiosity, but undefined reference to `get_tag' - this seems to be only one of the source files, so it's not a [mcve] either.

Note that the process entry point _start is not called according to the usual ABI convention, so the arguments are not in rdi and rsi.
